# Examine whether the set $\{(x,y):x²+y²=2; x>0, y>0\}$ is compact with usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^²$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I have to check whether the set is compact.

I used some of my prior knowledge of real analysis to check whether the set is closed but I'm not sure what I did was correct or not.

I know by Extended Heine Borel theorem that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Here is what I did.

$S=\{(x,y):x^²+y^² =2;x>0,y>0\}$
Here S is complement of the set $A \cup B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Where $A=\{(x,y):x^²+y^²<2;x>0,y>0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):x^²+y^²>2;x>0,y>0\}$
A and B are clearly open set and hence $A \cup B$ is open so there complement is closed.

This is what I did but then I came across and example in a book where the author picked up a sequence and showed that the sequence is not convergent in $S$ and so it is not closed.

What I did makes the set closed and what the author did makes the set not closed. I'm not sure what to do. I shall be grateful if you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac 1 n, \sqrt {2-\frac 1 {n^{2}}})$ is  sequence in this set which converges to $(0,\sqrt 2)$. The limit is not in  the set, so the set is not closed.

Comment: While choosing the sequence am I suppose to select x=1/n and y=underRoot(2-1/n) all the time in these kind of questions? And if the restriction of x>0 and y>0 was not given in the question then what I did is right or wrong?

Comment: Without the conditions $x>0,y>0$ your argument works. Whenever you see  a strict inequality your guess should be that the set is **not closed**. @SoumyajoyDas

Comment: Also how can I check whether the set is bounded or not?

Comment: @SoumyajoyDas $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$ implies that $-\sqrt 2 \leq x \leq \sqrt 2$ and $-\sqrt 2 \leq y \leq \sqrt 2$, so the set is bounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help